# Validate multiple select list

Tags: validation, select, jquery-validate

I've to validate a form like this with jquery validate plugin:

```
<form class="myform"
<select name="Input" id="input1">
<option value="DO0" opt_numAdults="2" opt_numChilds="0" >0</option>
<option value="DO1" opt_numAdults="2" opt_numChilds="0" >1</option>
<option value="DO2" opt_numAdults="2" opt_numChilds="0" >2</option>
<option value="DO3" opt_numAdults="2" opt_numChilds="0" >3</option>
<option value="DO4" opt_numAdults="2" opt_numChilds="0" >4</option>
<option value="DO5" opt_numAdults="2" opt_numChilds="0" >5</option>
</select>
<select name="Input" id="input2">
<option value="FP0" opt_numAdults="2" opt_numChilds="1" >0</option>
<option value="FP1" opt_numAdults="2" opt_numChilds="1" >1</option>
<option value="FP2" opt_numAdults="2" opt_numChilds="1" >2</option>
<option value="FP3" opt_numAdults="2" opt_numChilds="1" >3</option>
<option value="FP4" opt_numAdults="2" opt_numChilds="1" >4</option>
<option value="FP5" opt_numAdults="2" opt_numChilds="1" >5</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" id="mybutton">Go</button>
</form>
```

I need to stop user if he doesen't select **at least one of this 2 fields**.
I'm using this code, but it doesen't work...

```
$bt('.myform').submit(function(){

if($('#input1').val() == "" || $bt('#input2').val() == ""){

alert("Complete all fields!");

return false;

}

});

});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your custom validation code appears to have absolutely nothing to do with the jQuery Validate plugin.  Where is the `.validate()` method?

Comment: What is `$bt` supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of problems in your code:

- You say you want to use the jQuery Validate plugin, yet I don't see the plugin anyplace in your code.  You would at least have to include the plugin and call the `.validate()` method to initialize it.
- In your jQuery code, you use `$bt` as well as `$`.  I have no idea what you're trying to do here.  What is `$bt`?  In this answer, I'll just use `$` to reference the jQuery object.
- Your jQuery code appears to be custom validation code, but it's really nothing like the jQuery Validate plugin would use.
- Your opening `<form` tag is missing the closing bracket, `>`.
- For the jQuery Validate plugin to work properly, each input must have a unique `name` attribute.  Both of your `select` elements are named `Input`.  In my answer, I've renamed them to `Input1` and `Input2`.
- For the jQuery Validate plugin to validate `select` elements, the very first `option` element within each `select` must contain a `value=""` attribute.
- To require one item from a group of items, you use the `require_from_group` rule/method contained in the [`additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js).  Do not forget to also include this file.  Each `select` item in the group must contain a `class`.  I've also used the `groups` option to lump the error messages into one.

**HTML:**

```html
<form class="myform">
    <select name="Input1" id="input1" class="selectgroup">
        <option value="">please select...</option>
        <option value="DO0" opt_numAdults="2" opt_numChilds="0">0</option>
        <option value="DO1" opt_numAdults="2" opt_numChilds="0">1</option>
        ...
    </select>
    <br/>
    <select name="Input2" id="input2" class="selectgroup">
        <option value="">please select...</option>
        <option value="FP0" opt_numAdults="2" opt_numChilds="1">0</option>
        ...
    </select>
    <br/>
    <button type="submit" id="mybutton">Go</button>
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            Input1: {
                require_from_group: [1, ".selectgroup"]
            },
            Input2: {
                require_from_group: [1, ".selectgroup"]
            }
        },
        groups: {
            group: "Input1 Input2"
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/rj5Gw/**